# Input Search, how to disable the 'clear' X button

Tags: html, css

Generally in an `<input type="search">` you see a clear search `x` button when you type into the search field.

The code I've inherited doesn't have the clear search button, and I'm trying to wrap my head around why.

What are some methods of removing the clear (`x`) button?

Answer (score 1):

```
input::-ms-clear { 
  display: none; 
}
```